# How to automate restoration of Cpanel backup to another server

Tags: backup, cpanel, mirroring, whm

Cpanel has a built-in feature that allows automatic backup of accounts. Is there a way to automate restoration of it to another geographically separated server?

For example:

1. You setup daily backups from Server A.
2. You restore those daily backups to Server B as they come, overwriting previous restores.

Basically it's like having a standby server except the backup server's data is one day late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this it's not a backup/restore-over-write.

Best solution it's a failover solution.

Combine rsync (for any file on system and files cpanel (usr(local7cpanel & /var/cpanel/) + MySQL on mode Master-Slave

In this case, you have a clone copy of your system on other server ....

A nice day.